# Show textarea when choosing the option "Other.."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select item with in there a few options, and one of them is called "other..". What I want is that when a user clicks on "other.." a textarea will appear, I know this can be done with jQuery. Here is a short and simple version of my HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="opt4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="other">Other..</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="other_text" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know it can be done with jQuery? So where is your attempt?

Answer (score 5):

Add the `change` event to your dropdown list, which will [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the text field if the selected value is `"other"`:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('#other_text').toggle(this.value === 'other');
});
```

Comment: Do I have to hide the text field before doing this? Because the text field is already visible when I open my site.

Comment: @user3706620 If your default DDL value is not `"other"` then you should hide the text field.